# RVM per project gemsets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm

I'm having difficulty understanding RVM per project gemsets.  I've installed RVM and the 1.9.2 and 1.8.7 rubies, as per http://beginrescueend.com/interpreters/ruby/ , and when I want to start a new project, I've been

```
cd ~/Code
rvm use 1.9.2
rvm gemset create test1
rvm gemset use test1
gem install rails
```

But this takes a long time! (installing rails).  I then `rails new test1; cd test1`

I'm really unsure with the correct workflow.  If I'm making a new app to test in, I don't want to have to wait for rails to install.

It seems from http://beginrescueend.com/gemsets/basics/ that I can create a rails gemset, but then how do I create a per project gemset?

**Edit:**

If I'm going to using multiple ruby/rails versions, should I create a gemset, say `1.9.2@rails313`, then `rails new blah`, put `1.9.2@rails313` in `blah/.rvmrc` , and if I need to later on, create a `blah` gemset?

Comment: Not a direct answer, but an interesting read--["Vendor Everything" Still Applies](http://ryan.mcgeary.org/2011/02/09/vendor-everything-still-applies/) talks about a workflow that doesn't involve per-project gemsets and instead relies on Bundler's `--path` option. I've taken a liking to this method.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A gemset is just a container you can use to keep gems separate from each other.

The Big Idea: creating a gemset per project allows you to change gems (and gem versions) for one project without breaking all your other projects. Each project need only worry about its own gems. This is a Good Idea, and the wait time for installing large gems like Rails is usually worth it.

*That said*, if you're going to use the same version of Rails across all your projects and want to save time, you can install rails (and maybe rake as well) in the ['global' gemset](http://beginrescueend.com/gemsets/global/) - these gems are available in all gemsets *for that version of ruby*.

Assuming you already have a `test1` gemset:

```
$ rvm gemset use global
$ gem install rails
$ gem install rake
$ rvm gemset use test1
$ rails test1
```

Comment: Why is this necessary given `bundler`? Something is still not clicking for me with gemsets. I'm used to using different versions of Ruby and different versions of gems for different projects (e.g. with `rbenv`) and not also having to manage "gemsets" for each project.

Answer (score 1):

Once I wrote a simple blog post on [how to use RVM with gem sets](http://keepthingssimple.tumblr.com/post/11274588229/using-rvm-to-keep-things-simple), this might be helpful to you.

UPDATE: As the link above is dead, I believe it is in another location [here](https://everydayrails.com/2010/09/13/rvm-project-gemsets.html).

Comment: Cheers, that help clarify things.  Off topic, but you really need to change the colours, the lack of contrast kills my eyes.

Comment: Cannot find anything on that link, it gives me url requested not found.

Comment: I found what appears to be an active link and added it in an edit.